# How to define an Array with X nil values?

Tags: ruby

I have an `integer` with a value

I want to create an `array` with nil values representing this `integer`

For example:

```
i = 5
# The result i want is
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

What is the most Ruby way of doing this? Aka, the shortest way. Without need of looping et c.

Comment: It took you more time to write this question than it would have taken to check the [Array documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very basic question:

```
i = 5
Array.new(i) #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! Stackoverflow is for all kinds of questions :-) And since i couldn't find the answer for it here, I asked :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 5
[nil]*i #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```